# php not workng in javascript

Tags: php, javascript

sub1 is not working it is being called on the click of the button can use please help me 
how can i get values from php variables to javascript variable,

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript">

 function sub1()
 {
     var x=<?php echo $present; ?>;
     var y=<?php echo $min; ?>;
     var z=<?php echo $max; ?>;
     change(x,y,z);

     alert("hello");
     change();
  }


  function change(var no,var min,var max)
  {
       alert("hello1");
       var x=document.getElementById("show");
       x.src='<?php
           if($con==true)
           {
               $cmd="select * from showcase where item_no=3";
               if($res=$con->query($cmd))
               {
                    if($res->num_rows>0)
                    {
                        while($rw=$res->fetch_array())
                        {
                             echo "$rw[1]";
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo "no record found";
                    }
               }
               else
               {
                   echo "query problem";
               }
           }
       ?>'; 
   }
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

i am working on a slider which changes pic on the click of the button

Comment: you need to enclose the php code within quotes in js .like this `var x="<?php echo $present; ?>";`

Comment: What is the actual output of the code?

Comment: The right way to pass PHP variables into JS is `var x = <?php echo json_encode($present); ?>;`. Not wrapping it in quotes.

Comment: @DCoder Yes, for arrays and objects you have to use json_encode, but it's perfectly ok to use quotes for simple types.

Comment: @HeinAndréGrønnestad: Where "simple types" are "a number", "boolean `true`" and "a string that does not contain special characters such as newlines or double quotes". As I see it, it's easier to use `json_encode` all the time instead of thinking "do I echo this or encode it first?".

Comment: @DCoder I agree that it's safer to use `json_encode()` and I've updated my answer.

Comment: Also, instead of `<?php echo $var; ?>` you could write `<?=$var?>` which is shorter and more readable too IMO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit based on suggestion from @DCoder:**

You should use [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) which is able to output arrays, objects and complex strings safely:

```
var x=<?php echo json_encode($present); ?>;
```

*You could also just wrap the PHP output in quotes, but you would have to have full control over the contents of the variable. If you know that the variable is always going to be a number, a boolean value or a simple string without quotes, that should be safe too.*